# Regex to match repeated set of characters

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd like to be able to extract the following patterns from free text.

```
VBAV/123456.01
VBAV/132453.02
VSAV/132452.01.03
VMAV/142143.01.02
```

Currently I am trying as below but not much success

```
df["Project Id"] = df["WBS element"].str.cat(
df["Network VxAV"]).str.cat(
df["Text"]).str.cat(
df["Assignment"]).str.cat(
df["Reference"]).str.extract(
"(V[BSM]AV\/[\d]{6}[.0-30-3]{0,2})", expand=True)
```

The challenging part for me was to extract the patterns of repeated .01 or .02 or .03 at the end. This part can repeat between 0 to 2 times, hence my attempt with {0,2} with the regex.

What would be the right regex for this?

Comment: FYI: `[.0-30-3]` == `[.0-3]`

Comment: Changed your question to `pandas` and `python` (`df`?)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub How do I differentiate between .01, .02 and just .1, .2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r'V[BSM]AV/\d{6}(?:\.\d\d){0,2}(?!\d)'
```

Matches exactly 6 digits, and 0-2 instances of `.##`. `(?:xxxx)` is a non-capturing group.  Cannot be followed by another digit, so it won't match:

```
VBAV\1234567
VBAV\122346.123
```

You may need to adjust what can't follow the match.

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
V[BSM]AV/[\d.]+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/zHX8gH/1).

Comment: Also match 'VBAV/161010901011020160817',
 'VBAV/16101019010350',
 'VBAV/1610101901035020160817', Need exactly 6 digits after VxAV\

Comment: @idazuwaika: What does your comment mean?

Comment: edited. wanted to add new line, but pressing Enter at comment published it instead.

Answer (score 0):

consider the the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(txt.split('\n')) for _ in range(3)], ignore_index=True)
```

***Option 1***
my preference

```
s.str.split('/', expand=True)
```

[image]

***Option 2***
Also Nice

```
s.str.extract(r'(?P<first>\w+)/(?P<second>.*)', expand=True)
```

[image]

***Option 3***
Very Explicit

```
cols = ['first', 'second']
s.str.extract(r'(?P<first>V[BSM]AV)/(?P<second>\d{6}(.\d{2})+)', expand=True)[cols]
```

[image]